# Find a linear transformation between two subspaces in R3

Tags: linear-transformations

Find a linear transformation $f: R^3 ->R^3$ so that $f(S)=S'$

With $S$ and $S'$ being the following subspaces:

$S= \{(x_1,x_2,x_3)/2x_1-x_2+x_3=0\}$

$S'=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)/x_1-x_3=0\land x_1+2x_2-x_3=0\}$

**Attempt:**

I guess I could find a basis for $S$:
$$S=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac 12x_2-\frac 12x_3 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}=x_2\begin{bmatrix}
\frac 12 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}+x_3\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac12 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For $S'$ I solve the following matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\sim \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow \begin{matrix}
x_1=x_3 \\
x_2=0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
$$S'=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x_3 \\
0 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}=x_3\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I feel I should be onto something. But no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Good job! Now let $(u,v)$ be your basis of $S$ and $k$ your basis of $S'$. Choose any vector $w$ s.t. $(u,v,w)$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^3$ and define $f$ by (for instance) $f(u)=k,f(v)=f(w)=0.$